# "How to get username by userID in google assistant action?"

Tags: actions-on-google

I was connected my chatbot to google assistant action. They give only the userID, how to get username by using this userID?

Comment: Please update your question to show the code you're using to get the userID. There are a number of fields which this could be and how you use each.

Comment: @Prisoner i give that code below,please help

Answer (score 0):

You can get username without knowing userid, by the permissions [document here](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/helpers#user_information). You can take a look at [this sample code](https://github.com/actions-on-google/apiai-name-psychic-nodejs/blob/master/functions/index.js#L111).

Or you can use [account linking](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/) feature.

Tip! for userID, you can check out this [doc](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/user-info)

#### For Python:

There is no official library for developing google action using Python but,
You can add permission intent in `possibleIntent` array. So your Action SDK JSON will be,

```
{
  "expectUserResponse": true,
  "expectedInputs": [
    {
      "inputPrompt": {
        "richInitialPrompt": {
          "items": [
            {
              "simpleResponse": {
                "textToSpeech": "PLACEHOLDER"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "possibleIntents": [
        {
          "intent": "actions.intent.PERMISSION",
          "inputValueData": {
            "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.actions.v2.PermissionValueSpec",
            "optContext": "To address you by name and know your location",
            "permissions": [
              "NAME",
              "DEVICE_PRECISE_LOCATION"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "conversationToken": "{\"data\":{}}",
  "userStorage": "{\"data\":{}}"
}
```

Comment: thanks bro,but i am using python,how to use action sdk json file for get permissions

Comment: I updated the answer for Python. FYI, you can always mention programming language in question itself.

Comment: i am already tried,i don't know how to use,i can give my source code

Answer (score 0):

```
{`"actions": [
  {
    "description": "Default Welcome Intent",
    "name": "MAIN",
    "fulfillment": {
      "conversationName": "welcome"
    },
    "intent": {
      "name": "actions.intent.MAIN",
      "trigger": {
        "queryPatterns":["talk to Mr Bot"]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "description": "Rasa Intent",
    "name": "TEXT",
    "fulfillment": {
      "conversationName": "rasa_intent"
    },
    "intent": {
      "name": "actions.intent.TEXT",
      "trigger": {
        "queryPatterns":[]
      }
    }
  }],
"conversations": {
  "welcome": {
    "name": "welcome",
    "url": "https://ac752bb0.ngrok.io/webhooks/google_home/webhook",
    "fulfillmentApiVersion": 2
},
  "rasa_intent": {
    "name": "rasa_intent",
    "url": "https://ac752bb0.ngrok.io/webhooks/google_home/webhook",
    "fulfillmentApiVersion": 2
}
```

} }

this is my action.json,

class GoogleConnector(InputChannel):

```
@classmethod
def name(cls):
    return "google_home"

#def __init__(self):
#    self.out_channel = CustomOutput(url, access_token)

def blueprint(self, on_new_message):

    google_webhook = Blueprint('google_webhook', __name__)

    @google_webhook.route("/", methods=['GET'])
    def health():
        return jsonify({"status": "ok"})

    @google_webhook.route("/webhook", methods=['POST'])
    def receive():
        payload = json.loads(request.data)      
        sender_id = payload['user']['userId']
        intent = payload['inputs'][0]['intent']             
        text = payload['inputs'][0]['rawInputs'][0]['query']        
        if intent == 'actions.intent.MAIN': 
            message = "<speak>Hello! <break time=\"1\"/> Welcome to the Rasa-powered Google Assistant skill. You can start by saying hi."            
        else:
            out = CollectingOutputChannel()         
            on_new_message(UserMessage(text, out, sender_id))
            responses = [m["text"] for m in out.messages]
            message = responses[0]  
        r = json.dumps(
            {
              "conversationToken": "{\"state\":null,\"data\":{}}",
              "expectUserResponse": 'true',
              "expectedInputs": [
                {
                  "inputPrompt": {
                   "initialPrompts": [
                    {
                      "ssml": message
                    }
                  ]
                 },
                "possibleIntents": [
                {
                  "intent": "actions.intent.TEXT"
                }
               ]
              }
             ]
            })
        return r                

    return google_webhook
```

this my google connector python code,
how to modified this for account signin